# Is is OK to use boost's serialization this way?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Suppose I have a class in C++ like:

```
 class Smth {
   private:
     SomeType somethingOnlyChangedDuringConstruction; // may be something large,
                                                      // like a table
     int somethingChangeableDuringObjectUse;
   public:
     Smth(); // default constructor initializes first data member to the
             // appropriate value
     ...
 };
```

and I decide to serialize this using Boost's serialization. Is it "acceptable form" or "OK" if I just serialize the second member, and not serialize the first to save storage space, since the first is created on object construction? I rely on the default constructor (or some other constructor) being called to ensure the first gets initialized properly. Is this OK?

You might also want to ask: why isn't the first member static const? Well, it's not so, because one may have derived classes of Smth that initialize it differently, and there may also be derived classes of Smth which are not intended to be serialized and which do modify that member during use.

Of course, if that's itself a problem, *what's a better way*?

*What's this for?* I was trying to make a simple "Finite State Machine" implementation. The first member could be states or a transition table (actually, the FSM has both). Usually we don't want to serialize that, since it doesn't change throughout the use of the FSM and serializing it would therefore just waste storage space on disk, which I want to save. *Why not just use boost's statechart?* Well, I looked at it and I didn't think I needed all that functionality, and furthermore as I read the documentation to see how to use it, it seems it has "scalability" issues in terms of the number of states due to instantiating lots of templates, potentially exhausting compiler resources, which requires the use of "custom reactions" to overcome, but then there was a warning that custom reactions could "easily be abused" to the point of invoking the dreaded Undefined Behavior. Which sounded like the kind of thing that could potentially lead to weird bugs, and so I thought to try my own, simpler FSM system to try and keep the code safer.

Comment: If the data doesn't change, why is it a non-static member?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I mentioned why in the post. It may need to take on different values in different derived classes (a static is the same on all derived classes, which means it sets a value shared by all). Like in the FSM -- different kinds of FSM would have different transition tables.

Comment: We can't make decisions about you application domain. If you know the information to be redundant, then ***you*** decide whether it needs to be serialized.

Comment: @sehe: I was just wondering if the Boost system would allow for such a thing, that's all, or if it would be "abusing" the system and so could lead to something breaking. As all the examples showed serializing every data member.

Comment: @mike4ty4 Well, I though it would be kinda obvious since ***you*** always have to supply the `serialize` function for your types. Anyways, yes you can.

Comment: @sehe: Ah, OK, then. Just wanted to be 100% sure.